# Найти разность дат между двумя соседними строками в MS SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть SQL Server 11. Есть примерно следующая таблица `Statuses`

```
------------------------------------
| Id | DateTimeUtc         | Status |
------------------------------------
| 1  | 2020-02-08 15:23:00 | Moving |
| 2  | 2020-02-08 15:26:00 | Moving |
| 3  | 2020-02-08 15:29:00 | Moving |
| 4  | 2020-02-08 15:39:00 | Moving |
| 5  | 2020-02-08 15:43:00 | Moving |
| ...                               |
------------------------------------
```

Как я могу выбрать `Id` записей, у которых разность между предыдущим по времени статусом больше 3 минут? Ожидаю примерно следующее:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Statuses
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [current].DateTimeUtc, [prev].DateTimeUtc) > 3
ORDER BY DateTimeUtc
```

Данных много, поэтому желательно использовать эффективный по времени выполнения запрос. Из того что я находил, были функции `LAG / LEAD`, но в 11 версии их нет.

Comment: SQL Server 11.0 (released 20 May 2012) - это SQL Server 2012. И по части LEAD/LAG у него всё в порядке: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213234(v=sql.110) Даже  в 2008, где их нет, распрекрасно есть ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Akina да, я перепутал версию с годом :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без использования оконных функций:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM Statuses t1
JOIN Statuses t2 ON DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.DateTimeUtc, t2.DateTimeUtc) > 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Statuses t3
                   WHERE t1.DateTimeUtc > t3.DateTimeUtc
                     AND t3.DateTimeUtc > t2.DateTimeUtc )
```